# Can't assign to hline relative reference

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have the following org-mode table:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 1 :id global
| /Project/      | Mon | Tue | Wed |  Thu | Fri |  Sat | Sun | /Total/ |
|----------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+------+-----+---------|
| AnotherProduct |     |     |     |      |     | 2.50 |     |         |
| Prototype      |     |     |     | 3.50 |     |      |     |         |
|----------------+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+------+-----+---------|
| /Daily/        |     |     |     |      |     |      |     |         |
#+TBLFM: @I$9..@II$9=vsum($2..$8);%.2f;::@II$2..@III$9='(format "%3.2f" (apply '+ '(@I..@II)));N;
```

and I get the error `can't assign to hline relative reference` when I run `M-x org-table-recalculate`. I looked over the [org-mode references documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html) and the [gmane.org forums](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/86960), but I did not find any reasons as to why the hline relative references could not be assigned.

This issue is related to the `timesheet` package on MELPA. I have filed an issue here: https://github.com/tmarble/timesheet.el/issues/3 but hopefully I have found the underlying problem, and hopefully it is reasonably fixable.

Here is some relevant info:

- Org-mode version 8.3.1 (8.3.1-87-g4ef2c0-elpa @ /home/luke/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150824/)
- emacs-version: 24.5.1
- ArchLinux OS: Linux 4.1.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 17 08:52:28 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Consider asking the Org-mode maintainer for a better error msg, if you think a user is unlikely to understand the msg.

Comment: @Drew Do you have any suggestions about how I can ask the Org-mode maintainer? Is there an email or separate forum that I should use? I think the message can be improved, as I have been searching and do not understand it myself.

Comment: I think I will contact them at emacs-orgmode@gnu.org

Comment: Your example works OK on orgmode 8.2.10. However, there is an `@III` reference in a table with only 2 hlines. Try substituting `@III` by `@>`, which refers to the last row.

Comment: Too bad the error message didn't say something like @Juancho said: "*There is an `@III` reference in a table with only 2 hlines*". ;-)

Comment: Actually, after some testing, I realize that the `@I` and `@II` are causing the same error. I was able to find a workaround, outlined in my answer below.

Comment: It looks like the error message is explicit, although I would argue it isn't very intuitive. I updated my answer below. I think this is all cleared up!

Answer (score 5):

When I change the formula to the one below:

```
#+TBLFM: @2$9..@-1$9=vsum($2..$8);%.2f;::@>$2..@>$9='(format "%3.2f" (apply '+ '(@2..@-1)));N;
```

It works! Basically, I had to find a workaround from using the hline relative references `I` `II` and `III`.

**UPDATE**

I just heard back from the org-mode team, and here is their response:

> This is a known limitation: hline relative references are not allowed on the left hand side of a formula. The error message you get should be explicit.

After this clarification, the error message makes sense!

So, to re-introduce the hline references on the right side of my assignments would look like this:

```
#+TBLFM: @2$9..@-1$9=vsum($2..$8);%.2f;::@>$2..@>$9='(format "%3.2f" (apply '+ '(@I..@II)));N;
```

Comment: Hm, inspite of the info from the org-mode team `org-table-get-range` in `org-table-expand-lhs-ranges` should expand the range with relative hline-references on the left-hand side. (This is valid for org-mode 8.2.10 shipped with cygwin.) I tried it and it works.

Comment: The source code at http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-table.el;hb=HEAD has changed considerably but it seems that the essential lines are still in there. `org-table-recalculate` calls `org-table-expand-lhs-ranges` which calls `org-table-get-range` in turn.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround for the use of an hline-relative LHS formulas for in-table subtotals. I had the same problem as the OP, but found a reasonably flexible workaround using named fields. MWE:

```
|   | Breakfast                  |      Price |
|---+----------------------------+------------|
|   | Spam, eggs, and spam       |       2.35 |
|   | Spam, spam, eggs, and spam |       2.85 |
|---+----------------------------+------------|
|   | Breakfast Menu Total       |        5.2 |
| ^ |                            | bkfst_totl |
|---+----------------------------+------------|
|   | Lunch                      |      Price |
|---+----------------------------+------------|
|   | Spam sandwich              |       4.75 |
|   | Spam chunk                 |       3.50 |
|---+----------------------------+------------|
|   | Lunch Menu Total           |       8.25 |
| ^ |                            | lunch_totl |
|---+----------------------------+------------|
|   | Total                      |      13.45 |
#+TBLFM: $bkfst_totl=vsum(@I..@II) :: $lunch_totl=vsum(@IIII..IIIII) :: @>$>=$bkfst_totl+$lunch_totl
```